# What is the time complexity Big O of arr.at(-1) method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

What is the time complexity of arr.at(-1) method un Javascript?

I think it is O(1) since it is about accessing the variable using index as we do in python. Please make me sure.

Comment: The javascript standard does not mandate any time complexity for array methods, so it is implementation dependent.

Comment: Generally, it should be, but — runtime implementations (and performance guarantees) are not defined in [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.at). Why not profile some test code in the environment you're wondering about and find out for yourself?

Comment: The time complexity is the same as for `arr[arr.length - 1]`. Apart from (optimizable) constant-time function overhead, this costs one property lookup. What the time complexity of the lookup entails depends on how the Array is structured in memory by the implementation.